# Can't make function more polymorphic

Tags: haskell, types

I'm trying to define a function to return each of the nth [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).
This compiles,

```
unity n = map (cis.(*2).(*pi).(/n)) [0..(n-1)]
```

but its type defaults to `unity :: (Enum a, Floating a) => a -> [Complex a]`.
Of course, `n` needs to be an integer, as roots of unity aren't defined otherwise; but the returned Complex numbers will necessarily have floating-point coordinates; i.e, they cannot be `Complex Int`s. However, the following code won't compile

```
unity :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> [Complex b]
unity n = map (cis . (* 2) . (* pi) . (/ n)) [0..(n - 1)]
```

because `(/)` `(*)` and `cis` each constrain the return type (or Complex coordinate type in the case of `cis`) to be the same as the parameter type; so I get the error

> Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’

Is there a way I can force the parameter to be an integer without forcing the complex numbers to have integral components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is coerce your `Integral` parameter to a `Num` with `fromIntegral` when your code expects a value of the same type as the return type, i.e. as arguments to `cis`, `(*)` or `(/)`. Though `n` is only directly passed into `(/)`, so that's all you need to worry about:

```
unity :: (Integral a, Floating b) => a -> [Complex b]
unity n = map (cis . (* 2) . (* pi) . (/ (fromIntegral n)) . fromIntegral) [0..(n-1)]
```

Comment: Shorter: `unity n = cis . (2*pi/fromIntegral n *) . fromIntegral <$> [0 .. n-1]`.

Comment: Ah.. I'd tried (* 2 * pi / fromIntegral n), which failed, didn't realise the converse was possible

Comment: Yeah, it's because `infixl 7 *, /`, so `(*2*pi/n)` would be parsed as, like, `((*2*pi)/n)`, which doesn't work. The other way around, it's just parsed `((2*pi/n)*)`.